# how to follow and test the electrical diagram

Tags: peugeot, windshield-washer, peugeot-307

Hi I am working on a Peugeot 307 2001 petrol and my washer are not working I just need some help in understanding the electrical wiring diagram I have the manual.

This is the first time I have uses this site Anthony 25/02/2019 I am working in Great Britain

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! What troubleshooting have you done thus far? You really don't need a wiring diagram to start troubleshooting your issue. Easy things to check are fuses and relays, first.

Comment: Try tracing the wire back from the pump to find the switch, fuse etc.

Comment: I have now taken your advice,from your direction,and ordered Technician Automotive by Barry Holembreak,you will understand that I am trying to find my way with Motor V, M and repair.i have a haynes manual electrical systems,which a my studying for the wiring layouts, it would be helpful if you could give me some info on how to test a relay I have testing equipment.   Anthony